# Convert DataTable to Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I have the following DataTable

```
ItemNumber Quantity Order
1          2        3
4          3        8
7          7        9
```

I would like to load first two columns into 2 dimensional array. If it is not possible, at least I would like to get first column into 1 dimension array.

Of course, I can write a loop, but I wonder if it is possible to avoid loops.

Regards,

Comment: Why? if you think about it, a DataTable is just a glorified array.

Comment: Probably, because I have not thought about it. Thank you, Steve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't necessarily be able to *avoid loops* in the technical sense, but you could write something like this:

```
DataTable table = ...;

return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(c => new[] { c[0], c[1] });
```

That's an array of arrays, rather than a multidimensional array. But from what I've seen multidimensional arrays seem to be phased out as standard practice in most applications. You might also want to parse each row in that `Select` to being some actual type.

If you leave this as an `IEnumerable<>`, it will not need to loop more than the once that you use it, but if you're reading at random points a lot (using the indexer, or what have you), you might want to append `.ToArray()`. That decision depends on how you're using it. As a general rule, it's nice to write code that doesn't depend on random access like that, since then you don't have to read from the `DataTable` more than once per record.